# How to use networkLink update in geoXml3?

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3, kml, geoxml3

I tried a lot to use networklink tag.. to update a content in google maps Api v3.. but google support told me that networkling update is not supported in google maps.. only in earth.

So I found geoXml3 api.. but there isn't documentation ..
recently I found in http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/source/browse/branches/polys/geoxml3.js
that implements networklink, here a part of geoxml3.js code:

```
    *// Apply the link
    if ((networkLink.link.refreshMode === 'onInterval') &&
        (networkLink.link.refreshInterval > 0)) {
      // Reload at regular intervals
      setInterval(parserName + '.parse("' + networkLink.link.href + '")',
                  1000 * networkLink.link.refreshInterval);
    } else if (networkLink.link.refreshMode === 'onChange') {
      if (networkLink.link.viewRefreshMode === 'never') {
        // Load the link just once
        doc.internals.parser.parse(networkLink.link.href, doc.internals.docSet);
      } else if (networkLink.link.viewRefreshMode === 'onStop') {
        // Reload when the map view changes
      }*
```

Does anyone used or are using that? 
Are there some example of networklink using geoxml3 api ?

Answer (score 1):

My test cases for network links:

1. http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_local_network_link_test.html
2. http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_local_network_link_test_local.html

The major caveat of using geoxml3 is that without a proxy, everything needs to be on the same domain.

You might investigate [geoxml-v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/), it is a port to the Google Maps API v3 of the more mature GeoXml (from the Google Maps API v2).

Comment: Did you try to do something like show in
 https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/updates  ?

I contacted google enterprise support.. and they told me that's impossible to do in google maps.. due to, gmaps there's no support for networklink tag...

Comment: Hi.. When I putted that code above.. I think geoxml3 was walking to implement kml update method... In your example the only thing (correct me if i'm wrong) is test networklink tag parse.. not including update feature.